# How would you open a text file in Haxeflixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

How would you open a .txt file in Haxe flixel? I am primarily compiling for windows. Is there a function that looks like this:

```
sys.io.File.open(path);
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

What is your purpose? You could use [getContent](https://api.haxe.org/sys/io/File.html#getContent) to obtain content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFileContents:String = Assets.getText("assets/data/myfile.txt");
```

https://api.openfl.org/openfl/utils/Assets.html#getText

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.command('start ' + Paths.txt('yourtxtFileName'));
```